# Error en la sentencia switch en C++

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
class fecha{
    private:
        int dia,mes,anyo;
    public:
        void asignarfecha();
        void obtenerfecha(int *a,int *b,int *c);
        int fechacorrecta();
};

void fecha::asignarfecha(){
        cout<<"***introduce fecha***"<<endl;
        cout<<"introduce dia"<<endl;
        cin>>dia;
        cout<<"introduce mes"<<endl;
        cin>>mes;
        cout<<"introduce anyo"<<endl;
        cin>>anyo;
        };
void fecha::obtenerfecha(int *a,int *b,int *c){
    *a=dia;
    *b=mes;
    *c=anyo;
};
int fecha::fechacorrecta(){
    if(mes>0 || mes<13){
    switch(mes){
        case 1,3,5,7,8,10,12:
            if(dia<1 || dia>31){
                cout<<"error dia"<<endl;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if(dia<1 || dia>28){
                cout<<"error dia"<<endl;
            }
            break;
        case 4,6,9,11:
            if(dia<1 || dia>31){
                cout<<"error dia"<<endl;
            }
            break;
            default:
                cout<<"opcion invalida"<<endl;
        }
    }
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Error"<<endl;
    }
};
main(){
    int x,y,z;
    class fecha f;
    f.asignarfecha();
    f.obtenerfecha(&x,&y,&z);
    cout<<x<<"/"<<y<<"/"<<z<<endl;
    f.fechacorrecta();
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué clase de error?

Comment: no se si se separan con comas los casos

Comment: case 1,2,3: para tener varios en un solo case

Comment: Sería aconsejable que incluyeses el mensaje de error en la pregunta en vez de dejarlo como comentario

Comment: La funcionalidad de poner varios elementos en un solo `case` la he visto en Basic, mas no en C++.

Answer (score 2):

```
case 1,3,5,7,8,10,12:
  if(dia<1 || dia>31){
    cout<<"error dia"<<endl;
  }
  break;
```

Esta instrucción no es legal en C++. Hay que poner cada caso por separado:

```
case 1:
case 3:
case 5:
case 7:
case 8:
case 10:
case 12:
  if(dia<1 || dia>31){
    cout<<"error dia"<<endl;
  }
  break;
```

El separador de "*casos*" se encuentra en la sentencia `break`:

```
case 1:
case 3:
case 5:
case 7:
case 8:
case 10:
case 12:
  // ...
  break;

case 2:
  // ...
  break;

case 4:
case 6:
case 9:
case 11:
  // ...
  break;
```

Comment: gracias pense que se podia por eso queria preguntar

Comment: @EdwinCasco Los lenguajes de bajo nivel suelen tener menos _azucarillos_ para tratar con estos casos... se ve también en que `switch` no admite elementos que no sean numéricos o `char`

Comment: @EdwinCasco si la respuesta soluciona tu problema no olvides marcarla como "_solución_". Así tu pregunta será más util para futuros visitantes

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que switch acepte caracteres,o convirtiendolos en enteros que a su vez significan un numero dentro de tus casos, o simplemente usando '' en los casos.

```
char c ='a';

switch((int)c)
{
  case 97:
  {
   /* Code */
  } break;
}
```

O en el caso mas directo:

```
char c = 'a';
switch(c)
{
  case 'a':
  {
   /* Code */
  } break;
}
```